# How to start Selenium (Chrome Driver) on a profile, with cookies etc inherited, on Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Experimenting with things on Python, and want Selenium to fill out a form that is only available after adding something to a cart. I'm not sure how to set it up to have cookies/a profile on it beforehand. How would I do it?

Comment: This is not a question, what do you want us to help you with?

Comment: I'm asking about how I could start up Selenium with a profile, and the cookies I have on my normal Chrome. I'm using Chromedriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to start chrome using the `user-data-dir` command-line switch to specify the custom profile to use (otherwise it will create a new temporary profile).

For example:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/path/to/profile')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

/via https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: Thanks man. This worked.